# __str__() doesn't work after importing class

Tags: python, string, oop, import

I encountered a problem while importing a class: the **str**() doesn't work after importing the class

```
class unit:

    value = None
    node = None

    def __init__(self,value,node):
        self.value = value
        self.node = node

    def __str__(self):
        if self.node == None:
            return str(self.value) + " -> " + "Null"
        else:
            return str(self.value) + " -> " + str(self.node.value)
```

within the class file, the **str**() works as expected:

```
print unit(5,None)
5 -> Null
```

but when I import the class and test on the print function, it returns the object address instead of text pre-specified:

```
from unit import unit

new =  unit(5,None)
print new
<unit.unit instance at 0x000000000A8420C8>
```

Can you help me understanding what's going wrong?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. It can't run like it is shown here.

Comment: change your 'print new' to 'print (new)'. it works in python3

Comment: @chenchuk Would also advice to always consider print as a function so that my code can be treated as Python 2 and Python 3. But if the code is not supposed to be Python 3, it is not "necessary".

Comment: Working fine for me. Is this the recent change in your python file? If yes, did you recompiled your `unit` file?

Comment: To be sure that your __str__() is not working, you can also try to execute new.__str__() directly

Comment: Are you sure you're actually printing it, and not just typing the name in at the interpreter prompt (which would use `__repr__`, not `__str__`)?

Comment: @Matthias Yes I did try that, but I was getting an error msg : unit instance has no attribute '__str__'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put both `.py` files in the same directory, your `Python 2.7` code runs fine with a standard `CPython` interpreter such as `Canopy`. `Python 3.5` interpreters such as Anaconda will complain about the `print` not being used as a function and will thus not execute.

Since your `print` behaves as the default `print` implementation for objects, you need to recompile (`.pyc` files) the involved `.py` files. This can easily be done by restarting your kernel in some IDE.

Canopy IDE allows you to run a `.py` file again while the Python interpreter is still active. However, all objects created before this re-run stay the same and do not magically obtain your overridden `__str__` member method.