# Python -- __str__ does not work on import

Tags: python

I'm new to Python but I've been having this problem similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109677/str-doesnt-work-after-importing-class)

I'm currently running:

Python 3.6.7
  GCC 8.2.0
No IDE just plain *.py files

Here's my class:

```
class Point:                                                                                                                                  
    """ Point class represents and manipulates x,y coordinates """

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):                                                   
        """ Create a new point at the origin """                                    
        self.x = x                                                                  
        self.y = y                                                                  

    def __str__(self):                                                              
        return "({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)   

p = Point()
print(p)
```

I was curious why the `__str__` works on the same file but returns:

```
<point.Point object at 0x7eff98cc4c18>
```

after I imported to another.py file

My import file is this:

```
from point import Point
p = Point()
print(p)
```

I appreciate any input

Edit: The code I have here is all the code I've used to reproduce the bug. My guess is that this might be an error in my setup with Python3 in Ubuntu

Comment: Check your indentation, check your spelling, and check whether you actually used `print`. Make sure you're running the code you think you are. The code you've posted doesn't contain the bug you're asking about, so all we can do is give generic advice.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, too.

Comment: What does `ìmport point;print(point.__file__)` output in the second file?

Comment: @user2357112 The code I added is all the code I used to reproduce the bug. There is nothing extra after that. My guess is that there is a problem in the configuration I have with Python3 in Ubuntu since the __str__  is not giving the correct solution.

Comment: @RenatoFrancia: It would be nigh impossible for a configuration problem to produce that output from that code. It's much more likely that you're not actually running that code. Maybe you forgot to save. Maybe you're editing the wrong file. Maybe you have a stale `.pyc` file. Maybe you retyped your code instead of copy-pasting and made an error while retyping.

Comment: @RenatoFrancia `__str__` is a very basic function of Python. If it were broken as you indicate, likely major parts of a modern Ubuntu would not work. That would certainly be recognized. The breakage you describe doesn't really make sense in Python.

Comment: I agree about what you are saying. Weirdly enough I run it through vim, after running the suggestion from @isalgueiro it started running normally. So I guess it must've been a typo after all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Works OK for me.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5
$ python Point.py 
(0, 0)
$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Nov 18 2018, 02:06:39) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Point import Point
(0, 0)
>>> p = Point()
>>> p
<Point.Point object at 0x7fe04d5470f0>
>>> print(p)
(0, 0)
>>>
```

Comment: After testing your suggestion I found out what the bug was. Turns out that vim does not update "__ str __"  when calling it with "klen/python-mode" package. So I have to restart vim each time I run a python script while running it. This is probably to some cache generated before running the script.